# Codeigniter encrypted url not allowing in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I have this simple URL which generated by codeigniter encryption class (CI3.1.3)

```
http://localhost/pothdekhun/routes/map/c25075fb22389ec4f07fcdf808ebd9cb8722507ba471f21daebf3aea2fd72cf37a31f4e609b7f92348db5ca83015461f1b3ae38b2ca4ef2ced1fea02032fa33eu5lVujYy3cwTnlCZJS4545XqvLoQYQr1/Mirpur/Dhaka/Kuril+Bishwa+Road/Khilkhet/Dhaka
```

This is always showing me

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

My config file

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

I have tried `a-z 0-9~%.:_\-+` and `a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\+` nothing happened. Keeping empty is not possible.

**Second Ques:** Is it possible to change `permitted_uri_chars` only for any particular method? I have tried in `routes` controller's `map` method

```
$this->config->set_item('permitted_uri_chars','');
```

not worked

Comment: we have permitted characters defined in config file it wont allow another characters if we want to use you can add that symbol in config file...

Comment: If the info needs to be encrypted, it has no place in a URL.

Comment: @RejoanulAlam any update ? solved ?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam  yes, I have solved by allowing `a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\+=,` in  `config.php`. I am observing now, if its raise any security issue then I'll go `POST` method

Answer (score 1):

1) Modify File:

> (application_folder)/config/config.php

2) Find For: "permitted_uri_chars"

3) Change the value to :

```
a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\+= --> $config['permitted_uri_chars'] =  'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\+=';
```